# Sql Server Backup and move backup file: How to cope with file permissions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, windows-vista, file-permissions

With our product we have a simple backup tool for the sql server database. This tool should *just* make a full backup and restore to and from any folder.

Of course, the user (usually an administrator) needs permission to write to the target folder.

To avoid the problem of not being able to perform a backup to a network drive, **I write the backup to a temp file in the Sql Server backup directory. Then I move it to the target folder.** This requires permission to delete the temporary file from the sql servers backup folder. Restore is the same in the other direction.

This seemed to work fine until someone tested it on vista, where the **user does not have write access to the backup folder** by default.

So there are many solutions to solve this, but none of them seemed to be really nice.

One solution would be to find another folder for the temporary file. Both the sql server user as well as the administrator performing the backup need read and write permissions. Is there such a directory?

Any other ideas? Thanks a lot.

---

**Edit:** Solution must work with Sql Server 2005 and 2008, C# 3.0 (Smo), Windows XP and Vista.

Comment: Why can't you manually put the correct permissions on whatever folder you use to hold the backup file?

Comment: It is installed by an installer and must work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. It is actually pretty simple if you know a bit more about Vista then I do.

The backup folder is configured the same way as under XP, but the administrator permissions are not available until the process is in elevated mode. To get there, I just needed to add a manifest to the executable which requires the administrator privileges:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Now I get an UAC when calling the application and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Applications performing backup operations can request to open files in the backup mode. What that means is that the application has the [SeBackupPrivilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791059.aspx) privilege and it opens files with the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag set:

> **SeBackupPrivilege**—allows file content
>   retrieval, even if the security
>   descriptor on the file might not grant
>   such access. A caller with
>   SeBackupPrivilege enabled obviates the
>   need for any ACL-based security check.

While this sounds technical and complicated, what it boils down to in practice is to copy the files using `ROBOCOPY /B`

Comment: And how can I delete the temporary file? (btw: It must also work on XP)

Comment: To delete the file you need to have permission. If you don't have permissions, then you must create the backup file into a folder where you will *inherit* permission from the folder settings. Use a qualified path on the BACKUP statement for this so that SQL does not use the default folder. There is no such folder by default (where both SQL service account and the user have such permissions), such folder has to be created and proper ACLs must be set during your application deployment (during setup).

Comment: eg: SQL service account is domain\sqluser. The application is installed by domain\user. During Setup the .msi creates a folder in the domain\user's profile for backups, c:\Users\domain.user\AppData\MyApp\Backups. It grants create and write access to inherited objects in the folder to domain\sqluser. When application runs, it passes to SQL the full path c:\Users\...\Backups\backupfile.bak. SQL has access to create the file, user has full control over the resulted backup file (inherited from folder).